# horizontal xml layout and layout_weight not working together

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I am trying to create a xml page design. 
Vertically, I have divided the whole screen into two equal parts.

In the lower part I would like to have the "Registrieren" button at the bottom. 
That is displayed correctly. 
Now I have the problem that the textview and the Button are not on one horizontal line.

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/fragment_registration_activity_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ads"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:weightSum="9"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           >
            <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner_textview"
                android:text="Hello," />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/registration_button_scancode"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="QR Code Scannen"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="25dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|right">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/registration_button_finish"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Registrieren"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And a screenshot how it looks at the moment:

[image]

So how can I get the textview and the button on one horizontal line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the android:layout_gravity to either "center" or "center_horizontal" for both. You currently have "center" for the Button which puts it in the vertical center of the section where it is supposed to be. The TextView is "center_horizontal" which centers it both vertically and horizontally. Make them both uniform and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `layout_gravity` of `registration_button_scancode` to `center`

Some thing like

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/registration_button_scancode"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="QR Code Scannen"
            />
```